# Sincronizar Bitbucket com Servidor Web

Tags: git, versionamento, bitbucket, sincronização

É possível sincronizar meu projeto no Bitbucket com meu servidor web? Ao invés de enviar o projeto via FTP, ele seria sincronizado com meu repositório Bitbucket sem ter a necessidade de enviar o projeto várias vezes (via FTP p/ servidor web e via SSH para servidor Git Versionamento).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível.

O que você precisa é clonar seu projeto do bitbucket a partir do servidor web.
[Aqui](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/Git-Essencial-Obtendo-um-Reposit%C3%B3rio-Git) você encontra como fazer o clone dentro do servidor usando o git.

Resumidamente:

```
git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/project.git
```

Isso vai copiar o projeto para a pasta atual.

Ai toda vez que você quiser atualizar o projeto.

```
git pull
```

Dentro da pasta do projeto.

Provavelmente você utiliza um servidor remoto. Então você precisa acessar por SSH seu servidor e executar estes comandos. Você pode automatizar esta tarefa com algumas ferramentas como o [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) no Java.